# Cross compiling lapack and blas for arm using gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I am cross compiling armadillo by following [Cross-Compiling Armadillo Linear Algebra Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263427/cross-compiling-armadillo-linear-algebra-library)
I am using : gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu to cross compile.
I get following error when I execute make blaslib

[Error I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNDdo.png)

Error : as: unrecognized option '-EL'

As per my understanding build is triggering gcc x86 'as' and not arm 'as'. How to fix this error?

Comment: Configure with `--with-as=path/to/arm/as` or use `AS=path/to/arm/as make`

Comment: @Genjutsu : AS=path/to/arm/as make didn't work. Can you please elaborate how to use --with-as=path/to/arm/as?

Comment: If `configure` does support it, you can use `./configure --with-as=path/to/arm/as && make`